# how to make a vim filetype plugin

Tags: vim, plugins

I want to make a filetype plugin(in fact `asm`) of vim. After Searching for a while on the Internet, i found that i should add a asm.vim in  ***~/.vim/ftplugin*** folder. So I added that new file ***asm.vim*** in that folder and wrote the following codes:

```
map <F7> oTest<CR><Esc>
```

a very simple vim script, only output the `Test` string in the next line. but i failed, when i opened an ***xxx.asm*** file and pressed `<F7>` button, nothing happened. Anything wrong with the code? any help appreciated!

Comment: Do you use `filetype plugin on` in your `.vimrc`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to ensure that Vim actually detects the filetype; `asm` is defined in `$VIMRUNTIME/filetype.vim`, and there is a syntax,  but no filetype plugin yet. Check that

```
:set filetype?
```

outputs `asm`. If not, you need to work on the detection.

You also need to have `:filetype plugin on` (in your `~/.vimrc`); otherwise, no filetype plugin scripts aren't loaded. Check with `:scriptnames`.

Also note that you should not define *global* mappings or commands in a filetype plugin. Use `:noremap <buffer> <F7> ...`.
You can check your mapping exists with `:verbose map <F7>`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! You inspired me. `:set filetype?` outputs `filetype=nasm`, and i thought maybe it is the code `let asmsyntax="nasm"` in .vimrc works. So i changed the ***asm.vim*** to ***nasm.vim***, and ***<F7>*** works now!